# Find optimal position of a node under constraints - Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, nodes, finite-element-analysis

[image]

I want to move the node at the center to a position so all triangle angles are closer to 60 degrees.

I am thinking of calculating the standard deviation of angles for each triangle and try to minimize it. Is there any other way?

Comment: Would you get the same effect w/ less work to minimize the deviation in the lengths of the edges?

Comment: I haven't thought about it. Maybe yes.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know if this would be exactly the correct answer, but I might start with finding the third point of each of the inward-facing equilateral triangles based on the outer edges, and then find the centroid of those calculated points. That should be at least close, if not optimal... Some sort of dynamic programming refinement could then be used to test/improve optimality...